# How to move nested div up two div levels to match parent?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a landing page utilizing bootstraps and jquery. One drawback is I can only change the html with jquery being that the html is hard coded by cms backend code and will reset the html when changed. So the only way to manipulate the code is with jquery. 
Long story short I have a form with input and labels tags. I am trying to turn one column of input and label tags into two columns. So far I have created a div tag with its own class, which will be the second column. Input and label tags have been added in this div with class name sec1col2, using jquery wrapAll function. However I am needing help on how to move this div from the two parent divs, so the sec1col2 div can move next to the parent div, under the row div. 
Also there is more than one div with col-xs-12 class name in descending rows within the html file, so its trick trying to target just the one col-xs-12 class the sec1col2 div is nested in.

So far I have tried to the .unwrap() jquery function.  This has only moved the sec1col2 div up one level.
Thanks for any assistance with this.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="left-aligned-control field-control-wrapper">
        <div>
            <input value="AlternateEnergy" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item1</label><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input value="Audio" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item2</label><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input value="Broadcast" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item3</label><br>
        </div>
        <div><input value="Communications" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item4</label><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 sec1col2">
                <input value="Computing" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item5</label>
                <input value="Industrial" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item6</label>
                <input value="Instrumentation" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item7</label>
                <input value="Lighting" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item8</label></div><br>
            </div>

    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                        var $sect1inputcol2 = $('input[value=Computing],input[value=Industrial],input[value=Instrumentation],input[value=Lighting]');
                        var $sect1label5col2 = $('label')[5];
                        var $sect1label6col2 = $('label')[6];
                        var $sect1label7col2 = $('label')[7];
                        var $sect1label8col2 = $('label')[8];

                        $($sect1inputcol2).add($sect1label5col2).add($sect1label6col2).add($sect1label7col2).add($sect1label8col2).wrapAll('<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 sec1col2" />');

                        $('.sec1col2').unwrap()
            });
        </script>

         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I expecting to have the sec1col2 div next to the parent col-xs-12 div.

Comment: Is the posted HTML markup the original unchanged markup produced by the backend? **Or** the result you actually have achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the HTML markup you provided is *not* the original... But the one produced by your attempt to create a second column.

I will suggest you an other "attack angle" to resolve this. The advantage is that you won't have to code it specifically by the `name` attribute's value... And that will work for any amount of inputs from your original "one column".

That will allow you to add, remove or rename the fields... The column splitting is independent. That's a big advantage for the future developments of your web page.

So... It uses [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in a reverse loop, then [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to place the newly created second column after the first. The "reverse loop" simply is a normal loop, but decrementing... And starting from the last element, using the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Start from the inputs wrapper.
  var oneColumn_wrapper = $(".left-aligned-control");
  // Check how many divs inside
  var oneColumn_length = oneColumn_wrapper.find("div").length;
  // Determine what's the half amount of input group (And make sure to have a entire number, not a float)
  var half = Math.round(oneColumn_length/2);
  
  // Create the second column
  var secondInputWrapper = $('<div class="left-aligned-control field-control-wrapper">');

  // Using a reverse loop, append the half of the input groups in a second column
  for(i=oneColumn_length;i>half;i--){
    secondInputWrapper.append(oneColumn_wrapper.find("div").eq(i-1));
  }

  // Append that second column after the first.
  oneColumn_wrapper.after(secondInputWrapper);

});
```

```css
/* Some assumed CSS */
.left-aligned-control{
  float: left;
  padding-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="left-aligned-control field-control-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input value="AlternateEnergy" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item1</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Audio" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item2</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Broadcast" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item3</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Communications" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item4</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Computing" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item5</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Industrial" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item6</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Instrumentation" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item7</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input value="Lighting" name="checkboxes" type="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">item8</label></div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```